# How does apache use or allow browsing of /usr/share? (linux / Ubuntu)

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

The default apache.conf (ubuntu server), contains the following block:

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.

# .... other items removed for brevity    

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My intrepretation of this directive is that apache will allow web browsing of the items in `/usr/share` folder. yet If I try to browse and item in `/usr/share/` I cant view anything?

1. How do I browse the content in /usr/share?

   e.g. if I point a browser to `localhost/synaptic/html/index.html` I get a 404 not found error
2. If apache allows browsing of this directory - do I need to lock it down on a production server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to map a URL path onto /usr/share.  The simplest way to do that is to use an Alias directive, for example:

   ```
   Alias /share /usr/share
   ```

   Then `http://localhost/share/synaptic` will map to `/usr/share/synaptic`.  See the [documentation for Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).
2. All of the files in /usr/share should already be non-writeable for non-root users, including the Apache user, www-data.  They're probably also all world-readable.  So it should be fine to serve them all as above without any additional restrictions.  But if there are public files in /usr/share that you don't want Apache users to see, you can use `Require all deny` directives to block access to those files.

Comment: works perfect! The tricky part was working out which config file/section/container to insert the `Alias /share /usr/share` line. I put it in the default virtual hosts file, inside the `<virtualHost: *.80/>` block and before the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` container, thanks! (unable to upvote yet - not enough rep)